# Internal Server Error in Subdomains using PHP

Tags: php, subdomain, internal-server-error

My site is a subdomain.

When I load a file from a folder, which is in the root folder, it displays an internal server error in firebug.

Why does my subdomain displays internal server errors?

This is the php code:

```
 require_once 'xxx/test.php';
```

`xxx` is a directory in the root folder and I am trying to load the `test.php` page. That's where I got the internal server error.

Comment: What does the error log say? "Internal server error" is so generic that it's impossible to diagnose with the information you've given.

Comment: Are file permissions set properly? What about trying `echo file_get_contents('xxx/test.php');` or `print_r(is_readable('xxx/test.php'));` ?

Comment: can you check .htaccess file... some times it may be the reason for 500 internal server error!

Answer (score 2):

**check the logs**, most the time located at `/var/log/apache/php.errors` you can use `tail -f` in conjunction to monitor the log file while you refresh the page...

`tail-f /var/log/apache/php.errors`

**Check File permissions**, temporarily apply `chmod -R 777` to httpdocs (or whatever your http root is).

**Check PHP Code** A lot of times `"internal Server Error"` is caused by an error 500 which is generated when PHP code has a critical syntax error. Delete the require file, or try requiring another file with something simple such as `<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>` in it. If the error goes away then its most likely within that required file, check your syntax.. If you still can't figure it out.. post it up here.

**.htAccess error** Another cause can be problems with your .htaccess file, rename/delete it or comment all the lines out within. See if the error goes away, if it does check your syntax.

Comment: would be great to get a confirmed answer on this if my response answered your question.